# PHP output menu items links: array to convert to json

Tags: php, json, wordpress, navigation

I am trying to output a list of all links from my custom navigation in wp_head. My code kinda works, but for some reason, the links are being outputted funny looking.

I was expecting to get https://example.com/sample-page/

I got: \ / \ / as link instead of ://

Am I missing something obvious?

My code:

```
//OUTPUT MENU
  function get_nav_items() {

    $menu_slug_to_retrieve = 'my-custom-menu';
    $locations             = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu                  = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_slug_to_retrieve ] );
    $menu_items            = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
    $menu_items_json       = array(); // Prepare the array to convert to json
 
    // Loop it
    if ( $menu_items ) {
 
       foreach ( $menu_items as $item ) {
           $menu_items_json[] = array( 'url' => $item->url );
       }
 
       $html = sprintf(
           '<script type="application/ld+json" id="custom-json">%s</script>',
           json_encode( $menu_items_json )
       );
 
       echo $html;
    }
  }
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_nav_items' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much the expected output. What `json_encode` does is, it escapes all forward slahes by prepending a back slash. This can be convenient in case you include it in `script` elements. If you don't want the escaped forward slahes, you can tell php by adding this flag:

```
json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```